# Make half circle with content

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, css

I just wanted to make like this image. i have a word press site. i could not find any plugin for this kind of design. i tried it with CSS, JQUERY, html but "NO SUCCESS". how can i make this kind of design with content and image and icon?

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IeQV.png">
```

Comment: Use an SVG for that

Comment: This is also a good idea @LGSon. but i'll go with Prasad Kothavale's solutions.  because i want static, simple to understand and easy to edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I liked the design hence created snippet which might help you. You can use it as template just change image urls and text in html file. Feel free to adjust the components in css file :)

```css
.yellow-semi-circle {
  border-top-left-radius: 400px;
  border-top-right-radius: 400px;
  background: #FFEB3B;
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
}

.white-semi-circle {
  border-top-left-radius: 250px;
  border-top-right-radius: 250px;
  background: #FFF;
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  top: -250px;
  left: 150px;
}

.line-1 {
  border-color: #fff;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thick;
  position: relative;
  -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  width: 400px;
  top: -355px;
  left: 20px;
}

.line-2 {
  border-color: #fff;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thick;
  position: relative;
  -ms-transform: rotate(60deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
  transform: rotate(60deg);
  width: 400px;
  top: -450px;
  left: 100px;
}

.line-3 {
  border-color: #fff;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thick;
  position: relative;
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  width: 400px;
  top: -500px;
  left: 200px;
}

.line-4 {
  border-color: #fff;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thick;
  position: relative;
  -ms-transform: rotate(120deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
  transform: rotate(120deg);
  width: 400px;
  top: -480px;
  left: 300px;
}

.line-5 {
  border-color: #fff;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thick;
  position: relative;
  -ms-transform: rotate(150deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(150deg);
  transform: rotate(150deg);
  width: 400px;
  top: -415px;
  left: 380px;
}

.image-1 {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 309px;
  left: 130px;
}

.image-2 {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 193px;
  left: 191px;
}

.image-3 {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 123px;
  left: 317px;
}

.image-4 {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 123px;
  left: 447px;
}

.image-5 {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 193px;
  left: 556px;
}

.image-6 {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 309px;
  left: 623px;
}

.main-image {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 183px;
  left: 264px;
}

.text-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 288px;
  width: 100px;
  left: 36px;
}

.text-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 136px;
  width: 100px;
  left: 116px;
}

.text-3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 44px;
  width: 100px;
  left: 283px;
}

.text-4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 44px;
  width: 100px;
  left: 450px;
}

.text-5 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 136px;
  width: 100px;
  left: 615px;
}

.text-6 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 288px;
  width: 100px;
  left: 699px;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
  <div class="yellow-semi-circle"></div>
  <div class="white-semi-circle"></div>

  <!-- White Lines -->
  <div class="line-1"></div>
  <div class="line-2"></div>
  <div class="line-3"></div>
  <div class="line-4"></div>
  <div class="line-5"></div>

  <!-- Icons -->
  <img class="image-1" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designbolts/free-multimedia/1024/Photo-icon.png" />
  <img class="image-2" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designbolts/free-multimedia/1024/Photo-icon.png" />
  <img class="image-3" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designbolts/free-multimedia/1024/Photo-icon.png" />
  <img class="image-4" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designbolts/free-multimedia/1024/Photo-icon.png" />
  <img class="image-5" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designbolts/free-multimedia/1024/Photo-icon.png" />
  <img class="image-6" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designbolts/free-multimedia/1024/Photo-icon.png" />

  <!-- Center Image -->
  <img class="main-image" src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/130342/isolated/preview/d6de6adeed24d5339ba865e05e7cfa6b-flat-cloud-icon-by-vexels.png" />

  <!-- Text -->
  <div class="text-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
  <div class="text-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
  <div class="text-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
  <div class="text-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
  <div class="text-5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
  <div class="text-6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>

</div>
```

Comment: ohh Bro You make my day.. This is awesome one. Thanks a lot.